# Regex to find quotes not next to commas

Tags: regex

```
"FirstName","LastName","Address "goes here"","more"
```

I'm trying to get a regex that will find the quotations marks around 'goes here'.  I know it needs to find quotation marks that are not next to a comma or a line end, I'm just not sure how to get it done correctly.

Comment: there are a lot of possibilitys... show us what you tried so far

Comment: Nothing I've done is close yet... I know how to word what I want, just not how to write the regex.

Match " that is not ", ," or "\r\n

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this pattern

```
(?<=[^,\r\n])"(?=[^,\r\n])
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/173)

Comment: Thanks!  I had just found a tutorial on lookarounds and was getting to this answer, so this confirms that I was headed down the right path.

Comment: Wont match this quote "La,`"`"stName"